# Meta description with post excerpt vs custom text (or none at all)?

Tags: seo

I'm trying to understand what's the best option for SEO.

I have a blog based in Wordpress. By default it doesn't have any functionality to add meta descriptions to posts, so I'm wondering whether this is on purpose or if should I install a plugin to add them manually or even generate them dynamically with the post excerpt.

What are you doing in your blog today? And what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally best practice to manually add meta descriptions where possible, sometimes due to sheer the amount of content this isn't an option and it's better to scrap the important bits like the H1 Title.

In regards of using excerpt which will scrap the beginning information generally this might not be so desirable because the meta description should describe the entire page while the excerpt is generally used to start off i.e. (Read More..)

You should just install one of the many SEO plugins to add the custom fields, such as Yoast SEO.